# OCaml: describe modules in .mli file

Tags: ocaml

I am using Core.Std to generate a Set and a Map in a `.ml` file:

```
type temp = int with sexp, compare

type label = Symbol.symbol with sexp, compare

module Temp = struct
  type t = temp with sexp, compare
end
module TempComp = Comparable.Make(Temp)
module TempSet = TempComp.Set 
module TempMap = TempComp.Map

module Label = struct
  type t = label with sexp, compare
end
module LabelComp = Comparable.Make(Label)
module LabelMap = LabelComp.Map
```

How should I describe `TempSet, TempMap, LabelMap` in my `.mli` file?

I put:
`module TempMap : Map.S with type t = temp`

But I got an error:

> In this `with' constraint, the new definition of t
>          does not match its original definition in the constrained signature:
>          Type declarations do not match:
>            type t = t
>          is not included in
>            type 'a t = (Key.t, 'a, Key.comparator_witness) Map.t

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'a t` type is a type of maps from `temp` (a key) to `'a` (arbitrary data). What you're trying to say, is that `'a t` is a map from a key of concrete type `temp`, and the correct way of doing this is:

```
module TempMap : Map.S with type Key.t = temp
```

However, although it is a correct way of doing things it is not the straightforward, as it requires you to dig into the signature of the maps. The common way would be just say:

```
type temp
module Temp : Comparable with type t = temp
```

and allow the users of your interface to use `Temp.Map`, `Temp.Set`, etc. Also, consider using a richer interface `Identifiable` that will also include hashtables, hashsets, and many other useful and expected stuff.